# Swift Mixed type UIControl arrays for mass en\disable

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to disable a large group of various controls.  This works fine if the array is [Slider1, Slider 2, Slider 3] or any other set of matching UIControls.

```
let C = [Slider, Button, Label]
for control in C,  {
    control.enabled = B
}
```

Returns Error "Value of type UIView has no member 'enabled'." 
I'm assuming that when I mix types of UIcontrols it types the array as UIView.

Is there a way to make this work or another similarly efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Label`. While the `UILabel` has a member called `enabled` it is a *different* member than the one of `UISlider` and `UIButton`.

As you correctly mentioned the later ones inherit from [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled) which provides the member `enabled`.

The `UILabel` however does not. It just (coincidentally) defines a member called `enabled` as well. The compiler however does not really care about the naming of members. He looks for the first common super class which is `UIView` which does not have a member called `enabled` and thats it!

So your solution is to only combine actual `UIControls` in the array. The docs list the following:

- UIButton
- UIDatePicker
- UIPageControl
- UIRefreshControl
- UISegmentedControl
- UISlider
- UIStepper
- UISwitch
- UITextField

Looping over the labels would have to be done in a different / second loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `UILabel` and `UIControl` conform to a common protocol:

```
protocol HasEnabled : class {
    var enabled: Bool { get set }
}
extension UILabel : HasEnabled { }
extension UIControl : HasEnabled { }
```

Then you can either declare an array of the `HasEnabled` type:

```
let controls : [ HasEnabled ] = [ label, slider, button ]
for control in controls {
    control.enabled = true
}
```

Or declare an  array of `UIView`, but iterate only over the elements
which conform to `HasEnabled`:

```
let controls : [UIView] =  [ label, slider, button ]
for case let control as HasEnabled in controls {
    control.enabled = true
}
```

In the first case, the compiler ensures that only objects
conforming to `HasEnabled` are added to the array.

In the second case, arbitrary `UIView` objects can be added to
the array, but the loop body is only executed for those conforming
to `HasEnabled`.